# Why does Proto-Slavic first-person singular present form have nasalized o-sound?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Why does Proto-Slavic first-person singular present form have nasalized o-sound (ǫ) while PIE have longed o-sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thematic verbs in Proto-Slavic had the 1st p. sg. present suffix **-ăm > *-ŏn > *-ǫ* whose origin is really obscure. The most probable source of this suffix is by analogy with the athematic verbs which in Proto-Slavic retained the PIE suffix **-mĭ*, cf. Proto-Indo-Aryan **Hásmi* "I am", Ancient Greek *εἶμῐ* (eîmi) "I (shall) go" (from  Proto-Hellenic **éimi*), so in Proto-Slavic it is also **-mĭ* > Old Church Slavonic *-мь* [mʲĭ]: *есмь* (jes-mĭ) "I am", *дамь* (da-mĭ < **dad-mĭ*) "I shall give".